# What does it mean: to delgate to a baking service?

Tags: baking, delegating, delegation

What does it mean "to delegate to a baking service"? I have my Tezos in my Binance wallet. Is that considered to be delegating to a baking service?

Answer (score 4):

In layman terms, delegating means you are giving someone else, the baker, the ability to create new blocks using your tokens. Let me be absolutely clear that you are **never** transferring tokens to a baker. Your tokens are **always** 100% in your control. Bakers are rewarded for creating new blocks and typically share that reward with those that delegate to them. I suggest you go find a Tezos 101 document as understanding delegating is core/fundamental to Tezos.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i will read that document. I wonder if you can help me with one more thing: Binance is a Baker? or where can i find it?, thanks again!

Comment: Binance is an exchange that offers staking services to those that keep Tez in their account. They are NOT a public baker. I suggest that you not delegate to "the big exchanges" which creates a centralization of delegations. Use baking-bad.org to find a good baker.

Comment: we should also add that delegation also means allowing that baker to vote on your behalf for governance.

Comment: @MartinPortocarreroMonge please mark the question as answered